# Better map from Gmapping or Hector_Mapping?

Tags: navigation, mapping, hector-mapping, gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

Im trying to get a better pose estimation using a different methods like amcl or robot_pose_ekf and for that purpose I create a map from Gmapping and Hector_Mapping. So I like to try the both probabilistic approaches (amcl and robot_pose_eks )using the map from Gmapping and after that from Hector_Mapping. So my question is which map is better to be used??I have a bag file that have odometry , laser and imu.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61023/better-map-from-gmapping-or-hector_mapping??/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2013-04-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Both will produce similar maps; since you have odometry (& potentially a slow laser refresh rate?) it is probably better to use gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [Ernest](https://answers.ros.org/users/4002/ernest/) with karma: 341 on 2013-05-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1